# UIScrollView not scrollling, or being interactive for that matter

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have the following hierarchy:

VC -> UIView -> UISCrollView

the UIView happens to be the delegate of the UIScrollView, and owns the UIScrollView as an instance variable.

UIView .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ImageScrollView.h"


@interface Scroller : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>{

      ImageScrollView *scroller;
}


@end
```

.m:

```
#import "Scroller.h"

@implementation Scroller

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        DLog(@"");
        [self initScroll];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)initScroll{

    DLog(@"");
    scroller = [[ImageScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200, 200)];
    scroller.delegate = self;

    [self addSubview:scroller];

}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

    // Update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scroller.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    DLog(@"%d",page);

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    DLog(@"");

}
```

Note: as of now, none of the delegate methods get called. I see the UIScrollView on the iphone screen as a black box, however.

```
#import "ImageScrollView.h"

@implementation ImageScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        DLog(@"%f %f",frame.size.width,frame.size.height);
        [self configUI];
        [self configSelf];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)configUI{

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 400);
    self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

}


-(void)configSelf{

    self.scrollEnabled = YES;

}



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    DLog(@"");

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint _location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        [self processTouch:_location];
    }

    [self.delegate scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:self];

}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

     DLog(@"");

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint _location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        [self processTouch:_location];
    }


}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     DLog(@"");

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint _location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        [self processTouch:_location];
    }


}


- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Note: none of the touchesEnded or touchesMoved methods get called either in the IUScrollViewSubclass.

What am I doing wrong?

This code works however if I assign the view controller as the delegate to the uiscrollview

Comment: I've copied your code and do get delegate methods called - only difference is I made a dummy processTouch method as you did not include yours, and I am using a Xib whereas you are not(?) (i) can you add your processTouch method? (ii) can you add your viewController code that creates/initialises the scroller view?

Answer (score 0):

If I implement your code, it works fine.

To check more closely what is happening, I added this line:

```
NSLog (@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

at the start of every method.

If I **pan** inside the scrollView this is the log:

```
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] scrollViewDidScroll:
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] 0
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] scrollViewDidScroll:
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] 0
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] scrollViewDidScroll:
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] 0
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

Your touches methods don't get called as the touches are intercepted  by the scrollView's built-in panGestureRecognizer.

If I **tap** inside the scrollView this is the log:

```
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] touchesBegan:withEvent:
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] processTouch:
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] touchesEnded:withEvent:
ScrollViewTest1[4155:707] processTouch:
```

Touches called as the scrollView isn't grabbing the touch events for it's own gestureRecognizer.